# Is there an iOS app that uploads files to websites?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

My iPad can only uploads pictures to any website in the browser. My iPad is not jailbroken and I am not planning to jailbroke it. Is their an app in the App Store that can enable me to upload any file I want (ex: PDF, docs) to any website I visit. Their is a app called Iuploader that cost 15 dollars that does what I want but is a bit expensive in my opinion, is their any other app that does the same thing but is cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

iCab Mobile claims to support uploads.

https://appsto.re/gb/mKwxs.i

You will probably need to do an "Open in ..." to get it into iCab first.